# Package Python Script and Modules Into .rpm

Tags: python, packages

I have a command line python script that I'd like to distribute.  Being a PHP/Web guy, packaging software like this is a bit new to me.

The python script is simple, currently is run like this.

```
python /path/to/script -t -s some other argument
```

The python script requires an external library/package/module that is installed using it's own setup.py script.  Currently the user has to do this themselves.

What I'd like to do is have a single rpm that will install the library/package/module using the setup.py, then put my script in /bin (or wherever it needs to go in this case).

That way the end user can download the rpm, install it, and simply use the script like so.

```
script -t -s some other argument
```

How can I go about this?  None of the documentation, guides I've found is beginner friendly.  The target OS is CentOS 6.

*Yes, the licensing of the external library/package/module allows me to do this.*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you, just use the bdist group of commands. Like:

`python MyProgram.py bdist_rpm`

or also using --format option:

`python MyProgram.py bdist --formats=rpm`

This is just a quick view. So you can take a look at [documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/dist/creating-rpms.html) which explains how to create RPMs from python libraries.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking at the link earlier, but that's for 'modules.'  From what I understand about python, a module is more akin to a library that an actual script.  I need to distribute my script as a usable executable WITH a module.  Please tell me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @sajanNOPPIX ... so execute a module as a script??